# Why is the bolded text disappearing in chat?

Tags: bug, chat

[image]

The original message was:

> Right now, I think that this chatroom should be **for deciding what we're going to do in the next event, if it ever happens.**

And yet, the bold text disappeared. Why?

[image]

Comment: Can you link to the chat message? I am assuming the styling for bold text and for the "I am the OP" background are the color, but seeing the actual chat message would help confirm.

Comment: I can't reproduce this - what browser/OS are you using? Do you have any user styles being applied?

Comment: @oded Chrome v48.0, Windows Vista (64 bit). No user styles. http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27828968#27828968

Comment: @JohnB I'm a room owner. I'm pretty sure that's all.

Comment: @Mithrandir how the site itself looks like? How other text boxes look like?

Comment: @JohnB  It is... I unpinned it because of the bug.

Comment: Also, try closing the browser and open it again.  Do you see the bold text now?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Done, and.... Yup. [status-stupid-op]

Comment: Not stupid, it happens to me too, and was reported here several times. Since it can't be reproduced, and likely some odd Chrome bug, SE can't do anything about it. :/

Comment: @ShadowWizard If it's been reported several times, why wasn't this closed as a duplicate?[waits] Nu?

Comment: @Mithrandir well, because I couldn't find those past reports. Might be they got auto deleted due to negative score and no answers, or my search skills have failed me. :blush:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/981/discussion-between-shadow-wizard-and-mithrandir).